# Sorting SQL Server records by number of OR conditions matched

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-like

Suppose I have a (code-generated) query that is looking for keywords in a number of different fields. For example, any one of the terms `University`, `South` or `Africa` might be in the name field, or the address field, or some other field. I want to find all records where any of these fields match any of these keywords:

```
SELECT *
FROM
    Institutions
WHERE
    Institutions.name LIKE '%University%' OR
    Institutions.address LIKE '%University%' OR
    Institutions.name LIKE '%South%' OR
    Institutions.address LIKE '%South%' OR
    Institutions.name LIKE '%Africa%' OR
    Institutions.address LIKE '%Africa%'
```

However, this is going to pull up *everything*. I would like to sort by the records that match the most possible conditions.

I think this would work but looks pretty clunky:

```
SELECT *
FROM
    Institutions
WHERE
    Institutions.name LIKE '%University%' OR
    Institutions.address LIKE '%University%' OR
    Institutions.name LIKE '%South%' OR
    Institutions.address LIKE '%South%' OR
    Institutions.name LIKE '%Africa%' OR
    Institutions.address LIKE '%Africa%'
ORDER BY
    (
        CASE WHEN Institutions.name LIKE '%University%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
        CASE WHEN Institutions.address LIKE '%University%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
        CASE WHEN Institutions.name LIKE '%South%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
        CASE WHEN Institutions.address LIKE '%South%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
        CASE WHEN Institutions.name LIKE '%Africa%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
        CASE WHEN Institutions.address LIKE '%Africa%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    ) DESC
```

Is there something cleaner? I'm fine with SQL Server-specific solutions but pure SQL solutions would be great.

Answer (score 0):

You could use ranking with full-text search in sqlserver, but I think it is a bit overkill...

Anyway a few pointer:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142524%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc879245.aspx

Or if you create a function from the case-when thing which returns the count, you can use the same function in the where. (This is also hacky...)

Answer (score 0):

Your solution looks okay to me, but here's something else that should work (pseudo-code):

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT *,COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM
(SELECT * FROM I
WHERE name LIKE '%etc%'
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM I
WHERE name LIKE '%etc2%'
-- etc. )
GROUP BY *)
ORDER BY cnt DESC;
```

Comment: Yeah, I thought about doing UNIONs + COUNT too but I don't think it's an improvement in terms of readability. I also wonder about execution time; I'm thinking that using case statements on already filtered data must be faster than a bunch of UNIONs.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT i.*,
    (
      CASE WHEN i.name LIKE '%University%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
      CASE WHEN i.address LIKE '%University%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
      CASE WHEN i.name LIKE '%South%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
      CASE WHEN i.address LIKE '%South%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
      CASE WHEN i.name LIKE '%Africa%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
      CASE WHEN i.address LIKE '%Africa%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    ) AS rnk
    FROM Institutions i 
 ) result
 WHERE result.rnk > 0
 ORDER BY result.rnk DESC
```

EDIT: I forgot on [Apply](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

```
SELECT *
FROM
    Institutions i
CROSS APPLY
(
      SELECT
     (CASE WHEN i.name   LIKE '%University%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
      CASE WHEN i.address LIKE '%University%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
      CASE WHEN i.name    LIKE '%South%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
      CASE WHEN i.address LIKE '%South%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
      CASE WHEN i.name    LIKE '%Africa%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
      CASE WHEN i.address LIKE '%Africa%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as rnk
) c
ORDER BY c.rnk DESC
```

[Small example](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Comment: This is close to how I refactored my original solution.

Comment: @JordanReiter I think it is late, but I remembered on this question and add another solution.